# Splitting text containing word

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to split a text in paragraphs. The split should happen each at the beginning of each line containing following words INT. | EXT. |I/E.

This is the expression I use:

```
string[] res = Regex.Split(text, "(?=^.+?INT[.]|^.+?EXT[.]|^.+?I/E[.])"RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

It works fairly well but it also makes a new paragraph when a the line contains words such as PRINT. or TEXT.

How can I modify the REGEX expression so it fits the exact words  INT. EXT. I/E. ? I tried

```
"(?=^.+?\bINT[.]\b|^.+?\bEXT[.]\b|^.+?\bI/E[.]\b)"
```

but that doesn't work. Any ideas how I can make an exact word match?

Comment: I guess you have a typo: `)"RegexOptions.Multiline)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C#, you need to use verbatim string literals to declare regexps, or you may run into trouble, like here, where you have `\b` as a backspace and not a word boundary.

Use

```
@"(?=^.+?\bINT[.]|^.+?\bEXT[.]|^.+?\bI/E[.])"
^                ^            ^            ^
```

or contracted a bit:

```
@"(?=^.+?\b(?:INT|EXT|I/E)[.])"
```

Note that I removed `\b` word boundaries after the literal period because those word boundaries required a word character after the period. I think you do not need that.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to youю